# How to install package uploaded to CodeArtifact?

Tags: typescript, npm, aws-codeartifact

I just created an npm package (using typescript and node18 ) and uploaded it to Code Artifact.

As stated in [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/npm-auth.html) I used the following command to install the package

```
aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository repoName --domain domainName --domain-owner <Domain owner ID>
```

Instead I got `.npmrc` file and still can't use my package.

Any explanation why I'm still unable to use package or how can I do so?

Note: the domain name nor the repo are scoped

Comment: The command you shared just configures `npm` to use the specified repo. After you've done that, you still need to `npm install your-package`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the registry as codeArtifact. If you don't set the registry, your package will get installed from npm registry.

Try this command after running your login command:

```
npm config set registry https://{domain-name}-{accountId}.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com/npm/{repoName}/
```